# OPA Rego - How to do tag or label matching

Tags: opa, open-policy-agent, rego

I have...

1. List of tasks tagged with "must match" labels.
2. User tagged with labels.
   Now I want to filter only the tasks that match all task-tags with user-tags(user may have extra tags).

```
// rego-input:
{"
  user":"user-1",
  "tags":{"loc":"NY","type":"L1","group":"admin"}
  
}

// rego-data:
{
  "proj":"abc1",
  "tasks":[
    {"tags":{"loc":"NJ","type":"L1"},"title":"task-1"},
    {"tags":{"loc":"NY","type":"L1"},"title":"task-2"},
    {"tags":{"loc":"PA","type":"L2"},"title":"task-3"}]
}

// expected rego-output:
{
  "user":"user-1",
  "tasks":[
    {"tags":{"loc":"NY","type":"L1"},"title":"task-2"}
  ]
}
```

What is the right rego to get above output?, appreciate the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way of doing it.

```
package match.tags

import future.keywords.in

user := input.user
tasks[t] {
    some user_tags in input
    some data_tags in data.tasks[a]
    user_tags.loc == data_tags.loc
    user_tags.type == data_tags.type
    t := data.tasks[a]
}
```

Playground link with example: https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/6oCED9daS7

Comment: Thanks @peteroneilljr. I should elaborated about the tags. they are not predefined set of keys, so i can't do "tags.loc/type", they could be any numbers tag keys and any names/literals can be the tag key - in this case it's "loc,type", for other tasks it could be "abc, xyz, xto...". so the check have to be dynamic on any key strings in a loop or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I got something close... https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/wRYVBGTezT

```
usr = input.user
jobs2[v]  {
    some task in data.tasks
    some tk, tv in task.tags
    tv == input.tags[tk]
    v := task.title
}
```

But, it's not doing match-all(tags), instead it's returning task-1,2 by matching type "L1". wondering how to force the match-all...

Comment: There is no "force" function in OPA. Rego is designed to return exactly what you request. Was there something missing from the example code I shared?